# Footer and border acting weird with columns in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep my footer at the bottom of my page, but its acting weird with my columns. For some reason the content inside the footer stays where it's supposed too (most of the time), but the border assigned to the footer stretches all the way around most of my container element instead of just wrapping around the footer at the bottom.

Here's the css for my container:

```
#container
{
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    margin: 2% 10%;
    width:80%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
}
```

Here's the css for the footer:

```
footer
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5%;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
}
```

Here's the CSS for my columns

```
.col {
    float:left;
    width: 46%;
    height:90%;
    padding:0 2% 0 2%;
}
```

The footer is also inside the container div in my HTML if that helps.

I'm a complete beginner at HTML and CSS, and most of this code was taken from my professor, so any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you make a [sample fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) with your html code?

Comment: post your code in fiddle

Comment: First time using fiddle, so hopefully this works: https://jsfiddle.net/CameronCrane/ngyL2nyr/#&togetherjs=A5lb5qFzqc

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jzw9wL22/) that will always utilize 100% height while providing option to place footer to bottom while there is more content.

I used flex-box layout to do so.

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
    flex-grow:1;
    display:flex;
}
#footer
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    height:1.5em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
.col {
    height:90%;
    flex-shrink:0;
    flex-grow:1;
    margin:0 2% 0 2%;
}
```

**Edit 1**

As per given jsFiddle, [Here is another sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ngyL2nyr/1/) to fix the style using flexbox layout.
Hope it would suit your need.

Comment: Unfortunately this just threw my whole layout into chaos :/ Thank you for trying though!

Comment: @CameronCrane I tried to fix your provided layout fiddle. Please see the updated answer.